# Dio Wordprees _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Tags: wordpress, flutter, list, dart, dio

I am trying to connect to WordPress with Dio 4 and Flutter

I get the error in the repository

**ERROR**:
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')

[image]

**Repository**

```
Future<List<PostModel>> getPostsRequested() async {
    try {
      final response = await postApi.getPostsApi();


          final posts = ( (response.data) as List)
          // ERROR HERE 
          .map((e) => PostModel.fromJson(e))
          .toList();

      return posts;
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      final errorMessage = DioExceptions.fromDioError(e).toString();
      throw errorMessage;
    }
  }
```

**Api**

```
Future<Response> getPostsApi() async {
    try {
      final Response response = await dioClient.get(Endpoints.posts);
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

**Model**

```
import 'dart:convert';

class PostModel {
        PostModel({
                this.id,
                this.date,
                this.dateGmt,
                this.guid,
                this.modified,
                this.modifiedGmt,
                this.slug,
                this.status,
                this.type,
                this.link,
                this.title,
                this.content,
                this.excerpt,
                this.author,
                this.featuredMedia,
                this.commentStatus,
                this.pingStatus,
                this.sticky,
                this.template,
                this.format,
                this.meta,
                this.categories,
                this.tags,
                this.links,
        });

        int? id;
        DateTime? date;
        DateTime? dateGmt;
        Guid? guid;
        DateTime? modified;
        DateTime? modifiedGmt;
        String? slug;
        String? status;
        String? type;
        String? link;
        Guid? title;
        Content? content;
        Content? excerpt;
        int? author;
        int? featuredMedia;
        String? commentStatus;
        String? pingStatus;
        bool? sticky;
        String? template;
        String? format;
        List<dynamic>? meta;
        List<int>? categories;
        List<dynamic>? tags;
        Links? links;

        PostModel copyWith({
            int? id,
            DateTime? date,
            DateTime? dateGmt,
            Guid? guid,
            DateTime? modified,
            DateTime? modifiedGmt,
            String? slug,
            String? status,
            String? type,
            String? link,
            Guid? title,
            Content? content,
            Content? excerpt,
            int? author,
            int? featuredMedia,
            String? commentStatus,
            String? pingStatus,
            bool? sticky,
            String? template,
            String? format,
            List<dynamic>? meta,
            List<int>? categories,
            List<dynamic>? tags,
            Links? links,
        }) =>   PostModel(
            id: id ?? this.id,
            date: date ?? this.date,
            dateGmt: dateGmt ?? this.dateGmt,
            guid: guid ?? this.guid,
            modified: modified ?? this.modified,
            modifiedGmt: modifiedGmt ?? this.modifiedGmt,
            slug: slug ?? this.slug,
            status: status ?? this.status,
            type: type ?? this.type,
            link: link ?? this.link,
            title: title ?? this.title,
            content: content ?? this.content,
            excerpt: excerpt ?? this.excerpt,
            author: author ?? this.author,
            featuredMedia: featuredMedia ?? this.featuredMedia,
            commentStatus: commentStatus ?? this.commentStatus,
            pingStatus: pingStatus ?? this.pingStatus,
            sticky: sticky ?? this.sticky,
            template: template ?? this.template,
            format: format ?? this.format,
            meta: meta ?? this.meta,
            categories: categories ?? this.categories,
            tags: tags ?? this.tags,
            links: links ?? this.links,
        );

        factory PostModel.fromJson(String str) => PostModel.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory PostModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PostModel(
            id: json["id"],
            date: DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
            dateGmt: DateTime.parse(json["date_gmt"]),
            guid: Guid.fromMap(json["guid"]),
            modified: DateTime.parse(json["modified"]),
            modifiedGmt: DateTime.parse(json["modified_gmt"]),
            slug: json["slug"],
            status: json["status"],
            type: json["type"],
            link: json["link"],
            title: Guid.fromMap(json["title"]),
            content: Content.fromMap(json["content"]),
            excerpt: Content.fromMap(json["excerpt"]),
            author: json["author"],
            featuredMedia: json["featured_media"],
            commentStatus: json["comment_status"],
            pingStatus: json["ping_status"],
            sticky: json["sticky"],
            template: json["template"],
            format: json["format"],
            meta: List<dynamic>.from(json["meta"].map((x) => x)),
            categories: List<int>.from(json["categories"].map((x) => x)),
            tags: List<dynamic>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
            links: Links.fromMap(json["_links"]),
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
            "id": id,
            "date": date?.toIso8601String(),
            "date_gmt": dateGmt?.toIso8601String(),
            "guid": guid?.toMap(),
            "modified": modified?.toIso8601String(),
            "modified_gmt": modifiedGmt?.toIso8601String(),
            "slug": slug,
            "status": status,
            "type": type,
            "link": link,
            "title": title?.toMap(),
            "content": content?.toMap(),
            "excerpt": excerpt?.toMap(),
            "author": author,
            "featured_media": featuredMedia,
            "comment_status": commentStatus,
            "ping_status": pingStatus,
            "sticky": sticky,
            "template": template,
            "format": format,
            "meta": List<dynamic>.from(meta!.map((x) => x)),
            "categories": List<dynamic>.from(categories!.map((x) => x)),
            "tags": List<dynamic>.from(tags!.map((x) => x)),
            "_links": links!.toMap(),
        };
}

class Content {
        Content({
                this.rendered,
                this.protected,
        });

        String? rendered;
        bool? protected;

        Content copyWith({
                String? rendered,
                bool? protected,
        }) => 
                Content(
                        rendered: rendered ?? this.rendered,
                        protected: protected ?? this.protected,
                );

        factory Content.fromJson(String str) => Content.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory Content.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Content(
                rendered: json["rendered"],
                protected: json["protected"],
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
                "rendered": rendered,
                "protected": protected,
        };
}

class Guid {
    Guid({
        this.rendered,
    });

    String? rendered;

    Guid copyWith({
        String? rendered,
    }) => Guid(
        rendered: rendered ?? this.rendered,
    );

    factory Guid.fromJson(String str) => Guid.fromMap(json.decode(str));

    String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

    factory Guid.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Guid(
        rendered: json["rendered"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "rendered": rendered,
    };
}

class Links {
        Links({
                this.self,
                this.collection,
                this.about,
                this.author,
                this.replies,
                this.versionHistory,
                this.wpAttachment,
                this.wpTerm,
                this.curies,
        });

        List<About>? self;
        List<About>? collection;
        List<About>? about;
        List<Author>? author;
        List<Author>? replies;
        List<VersionHistory>? versionHistory;
        List<About>? wpAttachment;
        List<WpTerm>? wpTerm;
        List<Cury>? curies;

        Links copyWith({
                List<About>? self,
                List<About>? collection,
                List<About>? about,
                List<Author>? author,
                List<Author>? replies,
                List<VersionHistory>? versionHistory,
                List<About>? wpAttachment,
                List<WpTerm>? wpTerm,
                List<Cury>? curies,
        }) => 
                Links(
                        self: self ?? this.self,
                        collection: collection ?? this.collection,
                        about: about ?? this.about,
                        author: author ?? this.author,
                        replies: replies ?? this.replies,
                        versionHistory: versionHistory ?? this.versionHistory,
                        wpAttachment: wpAttachment ?? this.wpAttachment,
                        wpTerm: wpTerm ?? this.wpTerm,
                        curies: curies ?? this.curies,
                );

        factory Links.fromJson(String str) => Links.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory Links.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Links(
                self: List<About>.from(json["self"].map((x) => About.fromMap(x))),
                collection: List<About>.from(json["collection"].map((x) => About.fromMap(x))),
                about: List<About>.from(json["about"].map((x) => About.fromMap(x))),
                author: List<Author>.from(json["author"].map((x) => Author.fromMap(x))),
                replies: List<Author>.from(json["replies"].map((x) => Author.fromMap(x))),
                versionHistory: List<VersionHistory>.from(json["version-history"].map((x) => VersionHistory.fromMap(x))),
                wpAttachment: List<About>.from(json["wp:attachment"].map((x) => About.fromMap(x))),
                wpTerm: List<WpTerm>.from(json["wp:term"].map((x) => WpTerm.fromMap(x))),
                curies: List<Cury>.from(json["curies"].map((x) => Cury.fromMap(x))),
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
                "self": List<dynamic>.from(self!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "collection": List<dynamic>.from(collection!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "about": List<dynamic>.from(about!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "author": List<dynamic>.from(author!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "replies": List<dynamic>.from(replies!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "version-history": List<dynamic>.from(versionHistory!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "wp:attachment": List<dynamic>.from(wpAttachment!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "wp:term": List<dynamic>.from(wpTerm!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
                "curies": List<dynamic>.from(curies!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
        };
}

class About {
        About({
                this.href,
        });

        String? href;

        About copyWith({
                String? href,
        }) => 
                About(
                        href: href ?? this.href,
                );

        factory About.fromJson(String str) => About.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory About.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => About(
                href: json["href"],
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
                "href": href,
        };
}

class Author {
        Author({
                this.embeddable,
                this.href,
        });

        bool? embeddable;
        String? href;

        Author copyWith({
                bool? embeddable,
                String? href,
        }) => 
                Author(
                        embeddable: embeddable ?? this.embeddable,
                        href: href ?? this.href,
                );

        factory Author.fromJson(String str) => Author.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory Author.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Author(
                embeddable: json["embeddable"],
                href: json["href"],
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
                "embeddable": embeddable,
                "href": href,
        };
}

class Cury {
        Cury({
                this.name,
                this.href,
                this.templated,
        });

        String? name;
        String? href;
        bool? templated;

        Cury copyWith({
                String? name,
                String? href,
                bool? templated,
        }) => 
                Cury(
                        name: name ?? this.name,
                        href: href ?? this.href,
                        templated: templated ?? this.templated,
                );

        factory Cury.fromJson(String str) => Cury.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory Cury.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Cury(
                name: json["name"],
                href: json["href"],
                templated: json["templated"],
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
                "name": name,
                "href": href,
                "templated": templated,
        };
}

class VersionHistory {
        VersionHistory({
                this.count,
                this.href,
        });

        int? count;
        String? href;

        VersionHistory copyWith({
                int? count,
                String? href,
        }) => 
                VersionHistory(
                        count: count ?? this.count,
                        href: href ?? this.href,
                );

        factory VersionHistory.fromJson(String str) => VersionHistory.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory VersionHistory.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => VersionHistory(
                count: json["count"],
                href: json["href"],
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
                "count": count,
                "href": href,
        };
}

class WpTerm {
        WpTerm({
            this.taxonomy,
            this.embeddable,
            this.href,
        });

        String? taxonomy;
        bool? embeddable;
        String? href;

        WpTerm copyWith({
            String? taxonomy,
            bool? embeddable,
            String? href,
        }) => WpTerm(
            taxonomy: taxonomy ?? this.taxonomy,
            embeddable: embeddable ?? this.embeddable,
            href: href ?? this.href,
        );

        factory WpTerm.fromJson(String str) => WpTerm.fromMap(json.decode(str));

        String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

        factory WpTerm.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => WpTerm(
                taxonomy: json["taxonomy"],
                embeddable: json["embeddable"],
                href: json["href"],
        );

        Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
                "taxonomy": taxonomy,
                "embeddable": embeddable,
                "href": href,
        };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `response.data` is `List<Map>` so when you try to map it it return   a `Map` to you, not `string`. So when you try to pars it with `fromJson` it gives you that error, you should use `fromMap`.

change this

```
final posts = ( (response.data) as List)
          // ERROR HERE 
          .map((e) => PostModel.fromJson(e))
          .toList();
```

to:

```
final posts = ( (response.data) as List)
          .map((e) => PostModel.fromMap(e))
          .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If json file begin with "{" try like this

```
//Try them, one of them will work
final posts = PostModel.fromMap(response.data);
final posts = PostModel.fromJson(response.data);
```

and change

```
 Future<List<PostModel>>
```

to

```
 Future<PostModel>
```

Else if begin with "[" , try

```
//Try them, one of them will work
final posts = ( (response.data) as List)
      .map((e) => PostModel.fromJson(e))
      .toList();
      
final posts = ( (response.data) as List)
      .map((e) => PostModel.fromMap(e))
      .toList();
```